# Calling virtual function on parent pointer

Tags: c++, polymorphism

I have a tree structure, created from derived classes from `Node`. Each `Node` has pointer to it's parent and a virtual function `Symbols()`. Here is simplified example:

```
struct Node {
    Node* parent;
    virtual const SymbolTable& Symbols() { return parent->Symbols(); }
}

struct A : public Node {
}

struct B : public Node {
    SymbolTable symbols;
    const SymbolTable& Symbols() override { return symbols; }
}
```

So in this tree structure, `A` nodes doesn't have `SymbolTable` and `B` nodes do. All I need to do is for the `Symbols()` method return first `SymbolTable` above current node, but it seems that the overridden method in B is never getting called.

Comment: [mcve] is required

Comment: Right now this will end bad if you have `A` nodes.

Comment: Well I'm trying to put together some minimal working example but so far it works all just as I expect it to work in my full program.

Comment: @MarošBeťko then you, probably, are calling this function on a partially destroyed instance, e.g. from destructor.

Comment: And don't forget to add virtual destructor

Comment: @ivaigult It's getting called from inside the middle of test case block. Also what I've noticed is that the SIGSEGV I'm getting shouldn't be from parent being null on root since I also tried throwing an exception if it's null.

Answer (score 0):

I just tried this and polymorphism-wise it works on my end.
This is the code I ran:

```
struct SymbolTable {
    int sym = 42;
};

struct Node {
    Node* parent{ nullptr };
    virtual const SymbolTable& Symbols() { return parent->Symbols(); }
};

struct A : public Node {
};

struct B : public Node {
    SymbolTable symbols;
    const SymbolTable& Symbols() override { return symbols; }
};

int main()
{
    B parent;
    A child;
    child.parent = &parent;

    std::cout << child.Symbols().sym << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The output of this is

```
42
```

as expected.

Therefore, the method of B is called.

However, be advised that if you have a Node of type A that has no parent the program will crash, because an invalid pointer is accessed (I initialized it to nullptr in this example, and so should you). In this example that would mean changing the type of *parent* to A. In that case the program will crash with an access violation (because the parent of *parent* is a null pointer).

Comment: *"the program will crash with an access violation"* - only if you are lucky, it's just plain *undefined behavior*